# MySQL sum plus count in same query

Tags: mysql, sql, rating, rate

I'm trying to get the rates from anonymous people plus the ones who are registered. They are in different tables.

```
SELECT product.id, (SUM( users.rate + anonymous.rate ) / COUNT( users.rate + anonymous.rate ))
FROM products AS product
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id_product = product.id
LEFT JOIN anonymous ON anonymous.id_product = product.id
GROUP BY product.id
ORDER BY product.date DESC
```

So, the tables are like the following:

```
users-->
id | rate | id_product | id_user
1     2        2           1
2     4        1           1
3     5        2           2

anonymous-->
id | rate | id_product | ip
1     2        2          192..etc
2     4        1          198..etc
3     5        2          201..etc
```

What I'm trying with my query is: for each product, I would like to have the average of rates. Currently the output is null, but I have values in both tables.

Thanks.

Comment: why not use [`AVG`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)?

Comment: I've tried in vain. `AVG(SUM(...))` ->  Invalid use of group function

Comment: Don't you see there SUM / COUNT?

Comment: Count counts records and not the sum of something :) Why not using count( fieldname ) or count(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..

```
SELECT product.id, (SUM( ifnull(ur.rate,0) + ifnull(ar.rate,0) ) / (COUNT(ur.rate)+Count(ar.rate)))
FROM products AS product
LEFT JOIN users_rate AS ur ON ur.id_product = product.id
LEFT JOIN anonymous_rate AS ar ON ar.id_product = product.id
GROUP BY product.id
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54b12/12)

Comment: Why do you only verify if the anonymous table is null value? The users can also be null.

Comment: I've seen your edit. But it's not working. It's not giving the average. I get the value of 6. I have two values (one in each table) with the rate of 3. It sums (3+3) = 6 but it doesn't make the average, which should be 3.

Comment: I got to the same solution as you 5 seconds ago. Thank you, it's working.

Comment: @wkaha where is ur sql fiddle

Answer (score 0):

First, you are getting a cross join for each product within the table.  This is not what you really want.  I think this is close to what you are looking for

```
SELECT p.id,
       (coalesce(u.sumrate, 0) + coalesce(a.sumrate, 0)) / coalesce(u.num, 0) + coalesce(a.num, 0))
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     (select id_product, sum(rate) as sumrate, count(*) as num
      from users u
      group by id_product
     ) u
     ON u.id_product = p.id left join
     (select id_product, sum(rate) as sumrate, count(*) as num
      from anonymous a
      group by id_product
     ) a
     ON a.id_product = p.id
ORDER BY p.date DESC;
```

Assuming that `id` is unique in the product table, you don't need an aggregation at the outer level.

Comment: I'm not trying to contradict you, but I do believe that is to much for what I want..maybe in th end you're right..I'm currently trying the solutions below like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54b12/1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use count and sum on joins if you group by

```
CREATE TABLE products (id integer);
CREATE TABLE users_rate (id integer, id_product integer, rate integer, id_user integer);
CREATE TABLE anonymous_rate (id integer, id_product integer, rate integer, ip varchar(25));

INSERT INTO products VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (4);

INSERT INTO users_rate VALUES(1, 1, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO users_rate VALUES(1, 2, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO users_rate VALUES(1, 3, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO users_rate VALUES(1, 4, 3, 1);

INSERT INTO anonymous_rate VALUES(1, 1, 3, '192..');
INSERT INTO anonymous_rate VALUES(1, 2, 3, '192..');

select p.id,
ifnull(
  ( ifnull( ( select sum( rate ) from users_rate where id_product = p.id ), 0 ) +
    ifnull( ( select sum( rate ) from anonymous_rate where id_product = p.id ), 0 ) )
  /
  ( ifnull( ( select count( rate ) from users_rate where id_product = p.id ), 0 ) +
    ifnull( ( select count( rate ) from anonymous_rate where id_product = p.id ), 0 )), 0   )
from products as p
group by p.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2add/8

I've check on sqlfiddle. When there are no rates 0 is given. You may change that.

Comment: its not correct bez its not corect for product id 3 and 4 its should be 3 bcz only on uesr rate it and it average should be 3 not 1 ....you get it wrong

Comment: the calculated results sum of rating/number user(reg+annymou) its wrong....so check it

Comment: @AmitSingh that's because of the parameters i use for ifnull. i've described that in my posting. you can choose whatever you want as parameters.

Comment: for product 3 and 4 ur user 1 give 3 rating to both than how its average is 1

Comment: @AmitSingh: would be great if you could remove the downvote :)

Comment: u are wrong its wrong for product 3 and 4 average should be 3 not 1.... bcz only one registered user give it rating... 3 so its averge rating for product 3 and 4 is 3 not 1 see careully..

Comment: for product 3 and 4 there is rating in users_rating table...ok so its avg rating is 3 not 1

Comment: @AmitSingh: You are right. I've corrected the failure. Should work now correctly

Comment: now it correct.....but mine is correct too...u can try... so remove ur downvote...too

Comment: @AmitSingh i can not remove the downvote. are you able?

Comment: if u can not remove so upvote it so peple dont get confuse... that itswrong answer

Comment: @AmitSingh it's ok too :)